# How to disable mouse movement in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

In my windows application I want to hide as well as disable any mouse movement because I'm handling it from within my application. I'm able to set the position of the cursor to a point, but if the user moves the mouse then it changes position.

How can I stop user input from moving the mouse?

Comment: Its is not duplicate just try to understand the functionality secanario .

Answer (score 3):

Make your form implement IMessageFilter. then use following code in your form to hide cursor but make sure mouse right/left clicking is disabled too

```
Rectangle BoundRect;
    Rectangle OldRect = Rectangle.Empty;

    private void EnableMouse()
    {
        Cursor.Clip = OldRect;
        Cursor.Show();
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x201 || m.Msg == 0x202 || m.Msg == 0x203) return true;
        if (m.Msg == 0x204 || m.Msg == 0x205 || m.Msg == 0x206) return true;
        return false;
    }
    private void DisableMouse()
    {
        OldRect = Cursor.Clip;
        // Arbitrary location.
        BoundRect = new Rectangle(50, 50, 1, 1); 
        Cursor.Clip = BoundRect;
        Cursor.Hide();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }
```

see : [Disabling mouse movement and clicks altogether in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698673/disabling-mouse-movement-and-clicks-altogether-in-c-sharp/2698843#2698843)

Comment: Thanks to response but its only hide the cursor, it will not disable the mouse movement..

Comment: actually this should keep the mouse at coordinates: `[50,50]` of the screen.

Comment: Shouldn't you attribute this code from the source you copied it from?  See [Disabling mouse movement and clicks altogether in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2698843/719186)

Answer (score 2):

Cursor.Hide() method.
It will still be movable, but hidden.
You could also handle the MouseMove event and set Cursor.Position.

Comment: This method only to hide the cursor, that doesn't mean that curor movement is disabled..

Comment: As i wrote "It will still be movable, but hidden".. :)

Comment: What namespace are you using? My cursor doesn't have position.